# T-sql range Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to do something similar to below.
I have the pseudo-logic below.
Just wonder how to implement this:

```
delete B
from
TableA A with (nolock), TableB B with (nolock) 
where A.BeginNumber <= B.startipnum and A.Endnumber >= B.endipnum

delete A
from
TableA A with (nolock), TableB B with (nolock) 
where A.BeginNumber => B.startipnum and A.Endnumber <= B.endipnum

update B
set endipnum = startnumber - 1
from
TableA A with (nolock), TableB B with (nolock) 
where A.BeginNumber < B.startipnum and A.Endnumber <= B.endipnum

update B
set startipnum = endnumber + 1
from
TableA A with (nolock), TableB B with (nolock) 
where A.BeginNumber >= B.startipnum and A.Endnumber > B.endipnum
```

Sample Data

**Table A**

```
BeginNumber EndNumber
----------      ---------
16843009    16843009
16843009    16843010
16843009    16843013
16843009    16843016
33686020    33686024
```

**TableB**

```
startipnum  endIPNum
----------      ---------
1488047401  1488047401
1504824617  1873923369
1890700585  1907477801
1924255017  2142358825
2159136041  2276576553
```

There are no columns to join on between the 2 tables.
Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of sample data from table A and table B? I don't really understand what you are needing to do.

Comment: I added it to the general body of the question above. The formatting is getting messed up.Please take a look.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting (put tables in code blocks to preserve the layout) so for the sample data you have provided what should be the results for running queries 1,2,3, and 4?

Comment: Thanks martin!
The code above is pseudo - code, there is no way I can run it.
There are no common cols between the 2 tables for me to join on.
Basically the two tables have ip addresses. I am trying to import a new bunch of blocked ip addresses into the primary table(which already contains the ip data). In the process, I am doing cleanup, so I do not delete, what I have in the primary table.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to stop you performing a join with an on clause of e.g. `ON 1=1` - which will join all to all - similarly, a CROSS JOIN achieves the same (and is a better way of doing it TBH).